# Customize Fastlane scan message to Slack

Tags: slack, fastlane

I'm working with **Fastlane** and now I'm trying to figure out how to send only two parameters on the slack message from the **scan action**.

The [slack action](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/slack/), has the *default_payloads* parameter, which let you choose the values that you want to send, on the other hand, [scan action (run_tests)](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/run_tests/), only has the *message* parameter.

I only want to send **Test Failures** and **Successful Tests** value to Slack.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the connection between `default_payloads`, `message` vs. "Test Failures" and "Successful Tests"? What other data is usually sent to Slack by `run_tests`?

Comment: When you ran `run_tests` it sends all the values that are default payloads in the **slack action** plus "Test Failures" and "Successful Test". I honestly don't know if there is a connection, I'm guessing that there is one.

Answer (score 0):

`run_tests`/scan defines what is sent to Slack (using the `slack` action internally) in this file:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/scan/lib/scan/slack_poster.rb

As you can see, the `fields` variable is filled with "Build Errors", "Test Failures" and "Successful Tests" before handing over to `slack`. There is no option to disable that, so your only way to now send Build errors (if that is actually what you don't want to send, your question is not really clear on that) will be to not create any (or create a PR for the `scan` code that adds that functionality).

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress any of the default payload components using the `slack_default_payloads` parameter. Presumably this parameter was added more recently.

More info here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/slack

Doesn't seem to be a way to add additional components except through the `slack_message` parameter.